# DriveApp.createBlob fails when using byte array (decoded from a base64 string)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a file on Apps Script from a byte array that is obtained by decoding a base64 encoded string.

```
var parameter = request.parameter;
var encoded = parameter.encoded;

var blob = form.inputFile.getBlob();
var encoded = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(blob.getBytes());
```

I don't know if this is the issue, but the base64 string comes from a POST request that comes from another script. This is the code I used to generate it.

```
var blob = form.inputFile.getBlob();
var encoded = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(blob.getBytes());
```

Comment: Was there an instance that you were able to get this working? You may want to check if the blob from `form.inputFile.getBlob();` has results. You may also want to include here the error you are getting. These are starting points to help you resolve the issue.